# The set of continuous $[0, 1] \to \Bbb R$ functions is a subspace of $\Bbb R^{[0, 1]}$

Tags: linear-algebra

In example 1.35.b of Sheldon Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*, on page 19, it is said that "the set of continuous real-valued functions on the interval $[0, 1]$" is a subspace of $\Bbb R^{[0, 1]}$.

I am confused why this result is interesting to us. According to the definition of $F^S$, isn't "the set of [...] on the interval $[0, 1]$" **equivalent to** $\Bbb R^{[0,1]}$? What did I miss?

Comment: You missed "continuous".

Comment: are you suggesting $R$ is NOT continuous in this context?

Comment: Page 19 of what? What edition? A book with the title *"Linear Algebra"* or *"Linear Algebra Done Right"*? What author? Candidate: *"[Linear Algebra Done Right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheldon_Axler#Books) (Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics) 3rd ed. 2015 Edition"* by [Sheldon Axler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheldon_Axler). ("*[Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undergraduate_Texts_in_Mathematics)* (ISSN 0172-6056) is a series of undergraduate-level textbooks in mathematics published by Springer-Verlag.".)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ is the space of **all** functions $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$.

The subset $C$ of functions $f \in \mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ which are continuous is claimed to be a subspace. Of course, not all $f \in \mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ are continuous.

For instance: define

$$f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R} \text{ where } f(x) := \begin{cases}
1 & x = 1/2 \\
0 & x \ne 1/2 \end{cases}$$

Then $f \in \mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ but $f \not \in C$. *(The continuity you're concerned about in the comments is not meant to be about $\mathbb{R}$, but of the functions themselves.)*

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly interesting in that the claim is that the subset $C\subset \Bbb R^{[0,1]}$ of *continuous* functions among *all* functions from $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb R$ is claimed to be a subspace.

So, first you need to convince yourself that the set of all such functions forms a vector space.

Then you can check for closure of the subset of continuous functions under addition and scalar multiplication.

Of course there are functions in $\Bbb R^{[0,1]}$ that are not continuous.  For one that is *very* discontinuous consider the characteristic function of the rationals, restricted to the unit interval $\chi_\Bbb Q\restriction_{[0,1]}:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ by $\chi_\Bbb Q\restriction_{[0,1]}(x)=\begin {cases}1\,,x\in\Bbb Q\\0,\,x\not\in \Bbb Q\end {cases}$.